# REST API Works in Browser, But Not Client

Tags: rest, post, methods, get

I am developing a REST API, and have found a very interesting problem.

When I access the resources in a web browser (in my case Chrome), everything works fine. However, when I access the resources using a REST client (Google Chrome plugin, web-based client, and a Java applet), NONE of the variables pass to the API. This happens both with GET and POST methods.

I have absolutely no idea why this would be the case, and it's proving very difficult to test the methods before putting them into production (especially with POST methods).

Please help!

Comment: Wnat exactly goes wrong? What error codes do you get? Also, you have a car in your profile. You must be a transformer.

Comment: post your rest methods,then you can get closer solutions

Comment: I am a transformer (name is Cadillac), and, for instance, I have an "echo" function for the GET method where all it does is spit out the variables passed to it. In the browser, it works without incident. However, in the clients, it just comes back <xml></item></xml>, and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it sounds it could be 2 things:

1. You are not correctly passing API parameters via your client or
   applet
2. A problem with authentication or cookie management. Does the API require any type of authorization?
3. Are you forgetting to set a necessary HTTP header?

Comment: I am inputting the correct X-API-KEY (what we're using) and all the variables just as I would in the browser with the ?key=value notation, but in the client.

Comment: Interesting - Normally I would think that an x-api-key is something you submit via HTTP header. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control of the API also or is it a third party API? If so, do the params arrive at all or do they arrive empty? What's the error code? - a 403 not authorized (which would make sense if the key doesn't pass) or something else due to missing params.

Try the intermediate step of doing it with CURL form the command line - that'll give you more detail on what's coming back.